# How to get distinct/unique attributes in xsl variable

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select=" .. some stmt .." />
<xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
    <xsl:value-of select="@ATTRNAME"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Would like to know how to find 'Rows' with unique/distinct attribute 'ATTRNAME' [ in XSLT 1.0 ].

Comment: possible duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012321/xslt-distinct-select-group-by

Answer (score 1):

Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is done using `xsl:key`. The following prints only the unique elements of the root element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="attrByVal" match="/*/@*" use="."/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/@*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('attrByVal', .)[1])]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ': ', ., '&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation:** First, we group all attributes of the root element by value:

```
<xsl:key name="attrByVal" match="/*/@*" use="."/>
```

Then, create a template that matches only the first element for each key in the group:

```
<xsl:template match="@*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('attrByVal', .)[1])]">
```

And ignore all the others:

```
<xsl:template match="@*"/>
```

Example input:

```
<root one="apple" two="apple" three="orange" four="apple"/>
```

Output:

```
one: apple
three: orange
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 2.0 solution :

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$Rows" group-by="@ATTRNAME">
 <!-- Do something with the rows in the group. These rows
 can be accessed by the current-group() function. -->
    </xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any suggestions for XSLT 1.0?