# XSL Grouped Count

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to extract unique values from an XML and how many times they occur.

I have been following the answer given in [Xslt distinct select / Group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012321/xslt-distinct-select-group-by) but my schema is a little different.

My XML looks something similar to:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <D>APPLE</D>
        </C>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C>
            <D>BANANA</D>
        </C>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C>
            <D>APPLE</D>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

Based on the code in the previous answer I have:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:key 
    name="C-by-DValue" 
    match="B/C/D" 
    use="text()" 
  />

  <xsl:template match="A">
    <xsl:for-each select="
      B/C/D[
        count(
          . | key('C-by-DValue', B/C/D/text())[1]
        ) = 1
      ]
    ">
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="' - '"/>
      <!-- simple: the item count is the node count of the key -->
      <xsl:value-of select="
        count(
          key('C-by-DValue', text())
        )
      "/>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this returns:

```
APPLE - 2
BANANA - 1
APPLE - 2
```

So the for-each-select isn't only matching the first instance of each text() value. Could someone point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to change

```
<xsl:template match="A">
    <xsl:for-each select="
      B/C/D[
        count(
          . | key('C-by-DValue', B/C/D/text())[1]
        ) = 1
      ]
    ">
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="' - '"/>
      <!-- simple: the item count is the node count of the key -->
      <xsl:value-of select="
        count(
          key('C-by-DValue', text())
        )
      "/>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

to

```
  <xsl:template match="A">
    <xsl:for-each select="
      B/C/D[
        count(
          . | key('C-by-DValue',.)[1]
        ) = 1
      ]
    ">
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="' - '"/>
      <!-- simple: the item count is the node count of the key -->
      <xsl:value-of select="
        count(
          key('C-by-DValue', text())
        )
      "/>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2):

**It is possible to accomplish this grouping task in a much shorter way, never using `xsl:for-each` .**

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kDByVal" match="D" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="D[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kDByVal', .)[1])]">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(., ' - ', count(key('kDByVal', .)), '&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <D>APPLE</D>
        </C>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C>
            <D>BANANA</D>
        </C>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C>
            <D>APPLE</D>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
APPLE - 2
BANANA - 1
```