# XSLT Group by + count based on several tag level

Tags: xslt

```
<result>
    <account id="123456">
        <missing_data missing_in="Archimede"/>
            <line_not_found db_table="PRODUCT" id="PDT">
            </line_not_found>
            <line_not_found db_table="ADRESS" id="ADR">
            </line_not_found>
        </missing_data>
        <missing_data missing_in="Cassiope">
            <line_not_found db_table="PRODUCT" id="PDT">
            </line_not_found>
            <line_not_found db_table="PRODUCT" id="PDT">
            </line_not_found>
            <line_not_found db_table="ADRESS" id="ADR">
            </line_not_found>
            <line_not_found db_table="ADRESS" id="ADR">
            </line_not_found>
            <line_not_found db_table="ADRESS" id="ADR">
            </line_not_found>
            <line_not_found db_table="ADRESS" id="ADR">
            </line_not_found>
        </missing_data>
    </account>
</result>
```

I would like to group and count the missing_data@missing_in and line_not_found@id

For example, in this case : 
Archimede - PDT : 1
Archimede - ADR : 1
Cassiope - PDT : 2
Cassiope - ADR : 4

I have to admit that I am a complete beginner to XSLT.
I tried to inspire from [Xslt distinct select / Group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012321/xslt-distinct-select-group-by) but the problem is not quite the same since my key is composite but from several XML tags.

My XSL :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:key name="missing_data_key" match="line_not_found" use="concat(../@missing_in, ',', @id)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="result/account">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
        <xsl:for-each select="missing_data/line_not_found[
    count(
        .|key('missing_data_key', @id)[1]
        ) = 1
    ]
">
            <ul>
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    ( absent dans 
    <xsl:value-of select="../@missing_in"/>
    )
    <xsl:value-of select="' - '"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="
        count(
            key('missing_data_key', ../@missing_in)[
                count(
                  key('missing_data_key', concat(../@missing_in,',',@id))[1]
                ) = 1
            ]
        )
      "/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT 1 mandatory on this project

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are grouping elements in XSLT 1.0 you have to use Muenchian Grouping for achieve what you are trying to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <!-- Use the following key to index all line_not_found elements
        in the document by their id -->
    <xsl:key name="line-key"
             match="missing_data/line_not_found"
             use="@id" />

    <xsl:template match="missing_data">
        <!-- Obtain information from current node before losing the
            context -->
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id()" />
        <xsl:variable name="location" select="@missing_in" />
        <!-- Obtain the first element of each group which parent is the current missing_data element  -->
        <xsl:for-each select="line_not_found[generate-id() = generate-id(key('line-key', @id)[generate-id(..) = $id][1])]">
            <!-- Counts the subset of line_not_found elements which are children of
                 the current missing_data parent (put into in a variable for clarity) -->
            <xsl:variable name="count-children" select="count(key('line-key', @id)[generate-id(..) = $id])" />
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($location, ' - ', @id, ' : ', $count-children, ' ')" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```