# Insert opening and closing HTML tags independtly using XSLT

Tags: html, xslt, variables, tags

I have used to the following variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="openTag">
<![CDATA[
<div>
]]>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="closeTag">
<![CDATA[
</div>
]]>
</xsl:variable>
```

And implemented in the following way:

```
<div class="root">
      <xsl:variable name="ownerid" select="Prp[@name='owner id']/@value" />
      <xsl:variable name="nextownerid" select="preceding-sibling::Node[1]/Prp[@name='owner id']/@value"/>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$ownerid = '-1'">
          <xsl:copy-of select="$LogText"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$ownerid &lt; $nextownerid">
          <xsl:copy-of select="$openTag"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$LogText"/>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$ownerid &gt; $nextownerid">
          <xsl:copy-of select="$openTag"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$LogText"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$closeTag"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$closeTag"/>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$openTag"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$LogText"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$closeTag"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </div>
```

The problem is that `div` tags are outputted as text and not recognized as HTML tags. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Have you considered just making it a separate template instead?

Comment: @sanjay_c0d3r You should *never ever* need this. If you find yourself trying to output opening and closing tags individually via XSLT, you are most definitely doing it wrong. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am new to xslt and I have tried using resursion but it gave rise to too many complications. I need to implement a tree-like structure in html using xslt. i'm implementing css to give the required indentation which is based on owner id(present as an attribute in the xml). for root ownerid=-1, for the first child its 0, 1 for the next and it remains the same if they belong to the same parent.

Comment: XML file : http://pastebin.com/MNmprKkX XSL file : http://pastebin.com/LGckNJjK

Comment: @sanjay_c0d3r: The best recommendation is to *stop* writing XSLT and read a good XSLT book first. XSLT isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Thank you for the advice. I will definitely do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the XSLT 1.0 transformation that you are *actually* looking for.

It creates a nicely nested tree of well-formed HTML without any `disable-output-escaping` trickery.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <!-- index Nodes by their owner ID -->
  <xsl:key name="kNodeByOwnerId" match="Node" use="Prp[@name = 'owner id']/@value" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
          body {
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: verdana;
            background-color: white;
          }
          div.root {
            padding: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
          }
          div.root div {
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            margin-left: 3em;
          }
          div.remark {
            margin-left: 2em;
          }
          img.icon {
            padding-right: 5px;
          }
          span.log {
            font-weight: bold;
          }
          span.log.fail {
            color: red;
          }
          span.log.pass {
            color: green;
          }
          span.log.info {
            color: blue;
          }
        ]]></style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <!-- output "top level" nodes, i.e. those with owner ID -1 -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kNodeByOwnerId', '-1')">
          <xsl:sort select="substring-after(@name, 'message ')" data-type="number" />
          <xsl:with-param name="containerClass" select="'root'" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Node">
    <xsl:param name="containerClass" select="''" />

    <xsl:variable name="messageClass">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Prp[@name = 'type']" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <div class="{$containerClass}">
      <img class="icon" src="./{$messageClass}.png" />

      <span class="log {$messageClass}">
        <xsl:value-of select="Prp[@name='message']/@value"/>
      </span>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="Prp[@name = 'remarks']" />

      <!-- output nodes that belong to this node (recursive!) -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kNodeByOwnerId', Prp[@name = 'id']/@value)">
        <xsl:sort select="substring-after(@name, 'message ')" data-type="number" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Prp[@name = 'remarks']">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(@value) != ''">
      <div class="remark">              
        <img class="icon" src="./info.png" />
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>              
      </div>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Prp[@name = 'type']">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@value = '0'">pass</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="@value = '4'">info</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>fail</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of an `<xsl:key>`. A thorough explanation how keys work can be found [in an earlier answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/955527/18771).

The code is pretty straight-forward, so you should have little trouble understanding what it does. Don't hesitate to ask if anything is unclear.

I'd strongly recommend putting the CSS code into a separate file.

Comment: I need to output the html part in accordance to the javascript code to display the output in the form of a tree. I have written the following code : http://pastebin.com/fyZG8a7N I need to give the expand and collapse image links to only those nodes having children. im not able to figure it out.

Comment: @sanjay I'm sorry. This is material for an entirely different question. We are talking XSLT in this thread. A comment on whether you actually took the time to understand my solution would have been nice.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for this code! I have checked your code as the right answer. I figured the rest out on my own! :)

Answer (score 9):

XSLT is a tree transformation language: it takes a tree of nodes as input, and produces a tree of nodes as output. It doesn't read lexical XML containing start and end tags, and it doesn't output lexical XML containing start and end tags. The input tree is constructed (usually) from lexical XML by a separate processor called an XML parser, and the output tree is (often) turned into lexical XML by a separate processor called an XML serializer.

disable-output-escaping is a hack whereby the XSLT processor sends out-of-band information to the serializer. As such it creates an undesirable close-coupling between the transformer and the serializer, which prevents your XSLT code working in a pipeline where there is no serializer (for example, Firefox).

It looks as if your logic is trying to tackle a "group-adjacent" problem: group all adjacent elements having the same owner ID. There are much better ways of tackling that problem in XSLT without using serialization hacks. In XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="owner-id">
  <div>
    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

It's a bit trickier if you're constrained to XSLT 1.0, but not hard: look for examples of "sibling recursion".