# How to use a XSL Transformation pipeline or two-stage transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I am trying to change one all-encompassing xsl stylesheet into a two phase stylesheet setup, where xml is translated into "ideal" xml in the first step, and the second step is merely formatting.

Initially, we have this xml (extraneous parts removed)

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl/storeFinancialReport.xsl" ?>
<storeFinancialReport>
  <ProductGroupEntry><ProductGroupCode>xz1</ProductGroupCode><ProductGroup>thing1</ProductGroup><Quantity>0.0000</Quantity><DiscountExcl>0.000000</DiscountExcl><SalesExcl>30.700000</SalesExcl><Sales>35.000000</Sales></ProductGroupEntry>
  <ProductGroupEntry><ProductGroupCode>xz2</ProductGroupCode><ProductGroup>thing2</ProductGroup><Quantity>13.0000</Quantity><DiscountExcl>0.000000</DiscountExcl><SalesExcl>1480.970000</SalesExcl><Sales>1688.310000</Sales></ProductGroupEntry>
  <ProductGroupEntry><ProductGroupCode>xz3</ProductGroupCode><ProductGroup>thing3</ProductGroup><Quantity>2.0000</Quantity><DiscountExcl>0.000000</DiscountExcl><SalesExcl>50.730000</SalesExcl><Sales>57.830000</Sales></ProductGroupEntry>
  <ProductGroupEntry><ProductGroupCode>xz4</ProductGroupCode><ProductGroup>thing4</ProductGroup><Quantity>2.0000</Quantity><DiscountExcl>0.000000</DiscountExcl><SalesExcl>40.450000</SalesExcl><Sales>46.110000</Sales></ProductGroupEntry>
  <ProductGroupEntry><ProductGroupCode>xz5</ProductGroupCode><ProductGroup>thing5</ProductGroup><Quantity>2.0000</Quantity><DiscountExcl>1.000000</DiscountExcl><SalesExcl>18.000000</SalesExcl><Sales>18.000000</Sales></ProductGroupEntry>
  <ProductGroupEntry><ProductGroupCode>xz6</ProductGroupCode><ProductGroup>thing6</ProductGroup><Quantity>4.0000</Quantity><DiscountExcl>10.080000</DiscountExcl><SalesExcl>62.900000</SalesExcl><Sales>68.420000</Sales></ProductGroupEntry>
</storeFinancialReport>
```

I'm now trying to create a separate template that does the translation, sums, calculations etc that can be reused, and then just have the html formatting in a second template in a main file that imports the file with the "Enrichment/idealising" template

So far, then, I have the below which in theory calls a template which will do the sums etc, stores this in a variable, and then this newly transformed xml as passed as a variable to the template that does the HTML formatting.

*Main/HTML Formatting file*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
extension-element-prefixes="set">
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
    indent="yes" />

<xsl:include href="scrap_book_enrichment.xsl" />

<!-- call Product Group Block -->

<xsl:template name="ProductGroupBlock">
    <xsl:variable name="buildProductGroupResultXml"> <!-- store the results of this template call to this variable -->
        <xsl:call-template name="buildProductGroup">
            <xsl:with-param name="buildProductGroupResults" select="//storeFinancialReport"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:call-template name="displayProductGroupResults">
        <xsl:with-param name="buildProductGroupResults2" select="$buildProductGroupResultXml" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="displayProductGroupResults">
    <xsl:param name="buildProductGroupResults2" />
    <xsl:for-each select="buildProductGroup">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="/" />
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="$buildProductGroupResults2/ProductGroupCodeText/text()" />
            </td>

            <td align="right">
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="$buildProductGroupResults2/ProductGroupQuantityText/text()" />
            </td>

            <td align="right">
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="$buildProductGroupResults2/ProductGroupDiscountExclText/text()" />
            </td>

            <td align="right">
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="$buildProductGroupResults2/ProductGroupSalesExclText/text()" />
            </td>

            <td align="right">
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="$buildProductGroupResults2/ProductGroupSalesText/text()" />
            </td>

            <td align="right">
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="$buildProductGroupResults2/ProductGroupSalesMinusSalesExclText/text()" />
            </td>

            <td align="right">
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="$buildProductGroupResults2/ProductGroupSalesExclPercentage/text()" />
            </td>

        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*Second imported file, that creates "ideal" xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets" extension-element-prefixes="set">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template name="buildProductGroup">
<xsl:param name="buildProductGroupResults" />
<xsl:for-each select="set:distinct($buildProductGroupResults/ProductGroupEntry/ProductGroup)">

        <xsl:variable name="ProductGroup">
                        <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                    </xsl:variable>

                    <buildProductGroup>
                        <ProductGroupCodeText><xsl:value-of select="$buildProductGroupResults/ProductGroup[text()=$ProductGroup]/../ProductGroupCode/text()" /><xsl:text> - </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$ProductGroup" /></ProductGroupCodeText>

                        <ProductGroupQuantityText><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($buildProductGroupResults/ProductGroup[text()=$ProductGroup]/../Quantity/text()), '0')" />
                        </ProductGroupQuantityText>

                        <ProductGroupDiscountExclText><xsl:value-of
                                select="format-number(sum($buildProductGroupResults/ProductGroup[text()=$ProductGroup]/../DiscountExcl/text()), '###,##0.00')" />
                                </ProductGroupDiscountExclText>

                        <ProductGroupSalesExclText><xsl:value-of
                                select="format-number(sum($buildProductGroupResults/ProductGroup[text()=$ProductGroup]/../SalesExcl/text()), '###,##0.00')" />
                                </ProductGroupSalesExclText>

                        <ProductGroupSalesText><xsl:value-of
                                select="format-number(sum($buildProductGroupResults/ProductGroup[text()=$ProductGroup]/../Sales/text()), '###,##0.00')" />
                                </ProductGroupSalesText>

                      <ProductGroupSalesMinusSalesExclText><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($buildProductGroupResults/ProductGroup[text()=$ProductGroup]/../Sales/text()) - sum($buildProductGroupResults/ProductGroup[text()=$ProductGroup]/../SalesExcl/text()),'###,##0.00')" />
                      </ProductGroupSalesMinusSalesExclText>

                        <ProductGroupSalesExclPercentage>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="sum($buildProductGroupResults/ProductGroup[text()=$ProductGroup]/../SalesExcl)=0">
                                    <xsl:text>0.00</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="sum($buildProductGroupResults/ProductGroup[text()=$ProductGroup]/../SalesExcl)!=0">
                                    <xsl:value-of
                                        select="format-number(number((  sum($buildProductGroupResults/ProductGroup[text()=$ProductGroup]/../SalesExcl)  div  (sum( $buildProductGroupResults/SalesExcl ) ) ) * 100), '###,##0.00')" />
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:text>%</xsl:text>
                        </ProductGroupSalesExclPercentage>

                    </buildProductGroup>
                </xsl:for-each>


</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I realise these are quite chunky, but I believe I've reduced it down as much as I can whilst keeping it real to what I need. We have a dozen or more sections like this, but I'm obviously missing a fundamental step to get this to work.

The intention is for the "enrichment" phase to create a different xml, what I've seen referred to as "ideal" xml for the formatting xsl to deal with. Unfortunately, it seems that when I run these files through the translator in eclipse it just mashes up the original xml and removes all formatting and clumps it together in a piece of text. There are probably several idea's I've misinterpreted here, but once I have this one section down, I imagine the others will fall into line a lot easier.

Many thanks

Mitch.

[ UPDATED 2013/08/06 ]

Due to the time spent unable to complete this, and the benefits we would gain in other areas, it has been decided to take the time to enable our reporting framework to inherently deal with pipelining xsls. As such, needing this functionality in one stylesheet is no longer a requirement.

Comment: Where are you running this XSLT? In a browser? I don't know of any browsers that support set:distinct.

Comment: For testing purposes at the moment, I am running them through Eclipse, however normally yes the end HTML is output to browser. 

The set:distinct section isn't stuff I've added, it was already there, so I have to assume it works as intended.

Comment: One problem with your replacement template is that in the "call Product Group Block" section, it uses xsl:call-template with a "select" attribute. It should only have the "name" attribute.

Comment: ...and the template `displayProductGroupResults` does not declare the parameter `departmentSalesFinancialGroup`

Comment: Thank you both, After spending a lot of the morning flipping between using a variable, not using a variable, etc, I've lost track as to what is and isn't supposed to be there. I will update my code, test, and update the question.

Comment: I believe the departmentSalesFinancialGroup parameter isn't required as it matches everything, the variable is only needed for the display, to keep a tally of the first phase.

Comment: From your input XML, please include the exact output you want to see.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach to this problem in particular and XSLT in general is misguided.

- Your input already is in an ideal shape, there is no need to have a "clean-up" transformation step.
- Don't work with named templates, use template matching.
- Don't work with `<xsl:for-each>`, use template matching.
- Use `<xsl:key>` for grouping.
- Don't mix markup and layout. Move presentation-related stuff (`align="right"`) to CSS.
- Last, but not least: **Don't (!!!)** use browser side XSLT. XSLT is for running on the server. (Yes. I know. You can, technically, run XSLT in the browser. Browser-side XSLT support is inconsistent at best, save yourself a headache and don't do it.)

I don't think there is a way to gradually improve your XSLT, so I rewrite it from scratch.

This is all you need:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.1"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
  extension-element-prefixes="set"
  exclude-result-prefixes="set"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="currencyFormat" select="'###,##0.00'" />
  <xsl:variable name="percentageFormat" select="'0.00%'" />

  <xsl:key name="kProductGroup" match="ProductGroupEntry" use="ProductGroupCode" />

  <xsl:template match="storeFinancialReport">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ProductGroupEntry" mode="byGroupCode" />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ProductGroupEntry" mode="byGroupCode">
    <xsl:variable name="inThisGroup" select="key('kProductGroup', ProductGroupCode)" />

    <xsl:if test="generate-id(.) = generate-id($inThisGroup[1])">
      <xsl:variable name="sumQuantity"     select="sum($inThisGroup/Quantity)" />
      <xsl:variable name="sumDiscountExcl" select="sum($inThisGroup/DiscountExcl)" />
      <xsl:variable name="sumSalesExcl"    select="sum($inThisGroup/SalesExcl)" />
      <xsl:variable name="sumSales"        select="sum($inThisGroup/Sales)" />
      <xsl:variable name="netSales"        select="$sumSales - $sumSalesExcl" />
      <xsl:variable name="pctSalesExcl">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$sumSales">
            <xsl:value-of select="$sumSalesExcl div $sumSales" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><xsl:value-of select="concat(ProductGroup, ' - ', ProductGroupCode)" /></td>
        <td class="num"><xsl:value-of select="count($inThisGroup)" /></td>
        <td class="num"><xsl:value-of select="format-number($sumQuantity, '0')" /></td>
        <td class="num"><xsl:value-of select="format-number($sumDiscountExcl, $currencyFormat)" /></td>
        <td class="num"><xsl:value-of select="format-number($sumSalesExcl, $currencyFormat)" /></td>
        <td class="num"><xsl:value-of select="format-number($sumSales, $currencyFormat)" /></td>
        <td class="num"><xsl:value-of select="format-number($netSales, $currencyFormat)" /></td>
        <td class="num"><xsl:value-of select="format-number($pctSalesExcl, $percentageFormat)" /></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
thing1 - xz1   1    0    0.00      30.70      35.00     4.30    87.71%
thing2 - xz2   1   13    0.00   1,480.97   1,688.31   207.34    87.72%
thing3 - xz3   1    2    0.00      50.73      57.83     7.10    87.72%
thing4 - xz4   1    2    0.00      40.45      46.11     5.66    87.73%
thing5 - xz5   1    2    1.00      18.00      18.00     0.00   100.00%
thing6 - xz6   1    4   10.08      62.90      68.42     5.52    91.93%
```

See it live: http://www.xmlplayground.com/FmLo2Y

Further reading:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/955527/18771) explains how XSL keys work and how they are used in grouping.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4478126/18771) explains how `<xsl:apply-templates>` works.

Comment: Wow - Many thanks for obviously putting so much thought and work into your response. I will apply this and let you know how it goes. As for your comments regarding the more 'architecture' type responses, I'm afraid I fall squarely into the group of those who have a system framework, written years ago, without the means to change it, which eliminates changes to being browser-side XSLT and adding CSS. I should, at least, be able to take advantage of the different method for looping and grouping. - Again, many thanks!

Comment: Sorry, another aside, the data in is good for that section of the report, but the hope was that we would be able to add new lines to the xml that would later be used as summary sections of the report - thus doing the sums in a reusable stylesheet separately from the formatting. The "Clean-up" step would incorporate this additional data requirement. I should have been more clear on the original question. - To put this another way, the basis of the requirement is for a separation of calculation steps and formatting steps, so we may re-use the calc steps with a html formatted xsl, and a csv xsl

Comment: I understand. I'm afraid there is no way to pipeline two separate transformations in the browser. You can work with `<xsl:import>` or `<xsl:include>`. However, any "intermediate" step you do to pre-calculate values will result in what's called a *result tree fragment* (RTF) during transformation, and that is not directly usable for further calculations unless you have access to the [`node-set()` extension function](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/). Since you seem to reference EXSLT, I suspect you do. In any case, XSLT in the browser is cumbersome, inflexible and limited.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak, The expectation was to call the secondary "clean-up" file using `<xsl:include href="scrap_book_enrichment.xsl" />` as in the first xsl snippet in each of the subsequent "formatting" files. As I say, I am new to this area and only have the example reports in front of me as a guide, but yes, browser based xslt does indeed seem cumbersome. I have at least seen a much nicer version of the existing code, with attributes I'll be able to use in whatever I end up doing. Thank you.

Comment: I can not mark the question as answered, as it does not meet the requirement for setting out the logic in a separate file - I did try to mark it as useful, however, but apparently my reputation is insufficient - my apologies.

Comment: It's possible to write your solution as an answer to your own question and accept it. This way you can help others, too.

Comment: I hope I get that far :)