# Process nodes between two nodes or stop processing when reaching certain node XSLT 1.0 XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

Given:

```
<illustratedPartsCatalog>
    <figure id="fig1">...</figure>
    <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
    <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
    <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
    <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
    <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
    <figure id="fig2">...</figure>
    <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
    <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
    <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
    <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
    <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
</illustratedPartsCatalog>
```

Each figure gets its own table of `<catalogSeqNumber>s` but right now the figure1 table also includes entries for figure2 and vice versa. The processing of `<catalogSeqNumber>` should stop when it reaches the next figure.

Solved with Tomalak's answer:

```
<xsl:template match="illustratedPartsCatalog">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

I added this to the end of `<xsl:template match="figure">`

```
<xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][self::catalogSeqNumber] and ancestor::illustratedPartsCatalog">
    <xsl:call-template name="PI-TABLE"/>
</xsl:if>
```

And added this to PI-TABLE (which builds the table of `<catalogSeqNumber>`):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('kCSN', @id)" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<xsl:key>` can help you with that.

```
<xsl:key name="kCSN" match="catalogSeqNumber" use="preceding-sibling::figure[1]/@id">

<xsl:template match="illustratedPartsCatalog">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="figure" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="figure">
  <container>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kCSN', @id)" />
  </container>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="catalogSeqNumber">
  <!-- catalogSeqNumber processing ... -->
</xsl:template>
```

Here the key indexes all `<catalogSeqNumber>` elements by the @id of the immediateley preceding `<figure>`.

Now when we only process the `<figure>` elements, we can pull out the associated `<catalogSeqNumber>` elements easily with the `key()` function.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, Tomalak. I saw `<xsl:key>` used in a similar question but I couldn't figure out how to modify it.

Comment: There is an explanation of xsl:key I wrote earlier, maybe it helps you wrapping your head around it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948218/xslt-3-level-grouping-on-attributes/955527#955527

Comment: Danke, Tomalak.